# SUM total by year per user, group by user, dynamic columns for each year

Tags: mysql

This query was given to me and I need to make it dynamic so the year columns aren't hard-coded:

```
SELECT u.last_name as 'Name', 
COUNT(e.user_id) as 'Total',
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(e.datetime)=2012 THEN 1 END) as '2012',
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(e.datetime)=2013 THEN 1 END) as '2013',
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(e.datetime)=2014 THEN 1 END) as '2014',
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(e.datetime)=2015 THEN 1 END) as '2015',
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(e.datetime)=2016 THEN 1 END) as '2016'
FROM entries e, users u
WHERE e.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY e.user_id
```

Is there any way to create the year columns dynamically, and sum them dynamically using just mysql? I can of course do it with some php, but wondering if it's possible in pure mysql.

The current query outputs something like:

```
Name    Total 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016
Smith   568   186  124  162  75   21
Jones   579   188  156  160  68   7
```

Comment: You can't, really. This is a pivot query, and mysql doesn't support them directly. What you have is the standard workaround, and as you can see, it can't be dynamic. Do it on client-side code instead. it'll simplify your query

Comment: Gotchya. Will do, thanks, Marc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop round the results like this

```
$d = 2016;
$string = '';
for($i = 2012; $i <= $d; $i ++) {
    $string .= "SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(e.datetime)=$i THEN 1 END) as '$i'";
}
```

Then add it to the query

```
SELECT u.last_name as 'Name', 
COUNT(e.user_id) as 'Total',
    '.$string.'
FROM entries e, users u
WHERE e.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY e.user_id
```

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if there was a native mysql way to achieve the same thing, but that's easy enough. Thanks!